# JQuery hide not working after adding class to element

Tags: jquery, class, hide, element

I am currently developing a php app using Ajax, JQuery. And I encountered issues using JQuery for displaying my content.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-dark" id="table_beam"></table>
</div>
```

I can either hide my table by using

```
$('#table_beam').hide();
```

or I can hide the whole div by using

```
$('.table-responsive').hide();
```

But once I add couple classes to my table as follow:

```
<div class="table-responsive top tg">
    <table class="table table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table table-hover table-dark" id="table_beam"></table>
</div>
```

I cannot hide anymore using id element with

```
$('#table_beam').hide();
```

Comment: Please check for the extra classes in .CSS file , i am sure at least one of them have a style which cannot be overriden just by .Hide() jquery method. And also try with .css("display","none"); instead of hide.

Comment: No overriden css. And .css("display","none") is not working either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey several tips maybe can help you,

**1. [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)**

Maybe you should put the first parameter whose is `duration` of `hide()` by default is `400` so try this :

`$('#table_beam').hide(0);`

**2. Directly set ce CSS**

You can directly set CSS style like this : `$('#table_beam').css('display', 'none');`

**3. CSS Class**

My favorite method because if you don't have to call a callback after the `hide()` according to me there is more sense just set the class

`main.css : .table-hide {display: none}`

And you can set like this : `$('#table_beam').addClass(table-hide);` and remove like this : `$('#table_beam').removeClass(table-hide);`

Hope it's gonna help you :)

**EDIT** : I think this class `d-block` set `display: block !important`, so use my third method and with this following :  `main.css : #table_beam.table-hide {display: none !important}`

Comment: Yes, with !important this override d-block css, works perfectly thanks a lot.

Comment: Seriously bro?? :) :)

Answer (score 0):

The class `.d-block` has css `display:block!important` this will not allow .hide() to override the display. Please remove this class and find some alternative.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks bro! Appreciate it.